# iMac won't boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, backup, mac, iso

I have an iMac and I installed Ubuntu because Lion was causing my computer problems. But I still wanted a Mac OS so I brought it into the genius bar at Apple and they plugged it in and said they could dual boot the two operating systems (Ubuntu and Mountain Lion), but needed me to backup my files on Ubuntu and overwrite with OS X then reinstall Ubuntu. I brought it home to do the file backup and it won't turn on. I called Apple and they said bring it back in, but they don't know how it works and can't figure it out.

All I'm getting is a white screen and there is a bootable ISO on a CD in the drive that might be causing the problem, but I can't get it out. Finally I got the CD out by pressing F12 on startup, but it still won't turn on. Now I'm getting a flashing Icon of a folder with a question mark on it. I really don't want to lose my files on Ubuntu. I have month's worth of projects that I really want to keep.

Comment: If the Live DVD bricked the system, it sounds like a bug, you should report it to Launchpad.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out... I inserted the Ubuntu install CD and duel booted Ubuntu with Ubuntu and the computer booted fine.